# In Google Maps Javascript API v2(for Business License), How can I call Maps API correctly?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps API for Business version.
so, followed this document.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/clientside#v2
(surely, I registered my Website URL in Google Maps Admin.)

But, I got this error below.

> The Google Maps API server rejected your request. The "client"
>   parameter specified in the request is invalid.

when I use javascript API v3, there's no problem.

In business license, can't I use javascript API v2?

thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use V3? From what I remember with v2 you have to have an API key that is passed as a GET parameter in the hotlink (script tag) to the google api scripts. But from what I read on the link supplied something is most likely not configured correctly in the GMaps admin.

Comment: It's a legacy code:) At present, I know no API key is needed any more and no alert(invalid client parameter...) in free license.

Answer (score 1):

V2 apps require either a license key, or a client parameter. The client parameter is assigned to your company for particular URLs under your Maps API for Business license. If you have a client parameter, and it's not working, you should contact Google Enterprise support:

http://support.google.com/enterprisehelp/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142858&rd=1